# Setting Max Results in API v4 (python)

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

In v3 of the API I'm seeing that there was a max-results parameter that could be passed to get more than 1000 records. I haven't been able to figure out how to pass that parameter in v4 of the API using python.

My code looks something like below. I've commented out my best guess at max_result.

```
def get_report(analytics):
  # Use the Analytics Service Object to query the Analytics Reporting API V4.
  return analytics.reports().batchGet(
      body={
        'reportRequests': [
        {
          'viewId': VIEW_ID,
          #'max_results': 100000,
          'dateRanges': [{'startDate': '2016-04-01', 'endDate': '2016-08-09'}],
          'dimensions': [{'name':'ga:date'},
                    {'name': 'ga:channelGrouping'}],
          'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:sessions'},
                 {'expression': 'ga:newUsers'},
                 {'expression': 'ga:goal15Completions'},
                 {'expression': 'ga:goal9Completions'},
                 {'expression': 'ga:goal10Completions'}]
        }]
      }
  ).execute()
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The correct name of the parameter you are looking for is: [`pageSize`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet#ReportRequest.FIELDS.page_size). The [Reference Docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet) provide the full API specifications.

```
def get_report(analytics):
  # Use the Analytics Service Object to query the Analytics Reporting API V4.
  return analytics.reports().batchGet(
      body={
        'reportRequests': [
        {
          'viewId': VIEW_ID,
          'pageSize': 10000,
          'dateRanges': [{'startDate': '2016-04-01', 'endDate': '2016-08-09'}],
          'dimensions': [{'name':'ga:date'},
                    {'name': 'ga:channelGrouping'}],
          'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:sessions'},
                 {'expression': 'ga:newUsers'},
                 {'expression': 'ga:goal15Completions'},
                 {'expression': 'ga:goal9Completions'},
                 {'expression': 'ga:goal10Completions'}]
        }]
      }
  ).execute()
```

Note: the API returns a maximum of **100,000** rows per request, no matter how many you ask for. As you attempted `max_results` this tells me you are trying to migrate from the Core Reporting API V3, check out the [Migration Guide - Pagination documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/migration#pagination) to understand how to request the next 10,000 rows.

Stack Overflow extra tip. Include your error responses in your question, as it will likely improve your chances of someone being able to help.

Comment: Thanks a million! This took me forever to find.