# Google analytics API v4 max results

Tags: google-analytics-firebase

Can someone please help me for Google analytic API V4:
how to pass: max-result parameter with this class:
Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting
I am unable to find relevant function to assign max-result parameter value.

Answer (score 7):

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922925/1224827 , the parameter you're looking for is `pageSize`:

The correct name of the parameter you are looking for is: [`pageSize`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet#ReportRequest.FIELDS.page_size). The [Reference Docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet) provide the full API specifications.

```
def get_report(analytics):
  # Use the Analytics Service Object to query the Analytics Reporting API V4.
  return analytics.reports().batchGet(
      body={
        'reportRequests': [
        {
          'viewId': VIEW_ID,
          'pageSize': 10000,
          'dateRanges': [{'startDate': '2016-04-01', 'endDate': '2016-08-09'}],
          'dimensions': [{'name':'ga:date'},
                    {'name': 'ga:channelGrouping'}],
          'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:sessions'},
                 {'expression': 'ga:newUsers'},
                 {'expression': 'ga:goal15Completions'},
                 {'expression': 'ga:goal9Completions'},
                 {'expression': 'ga:goal10Completions'}]
        }]
      }
  ).execute()
```

Note: the API returns a maximum of **100,000** rows per request, no matter how many you ask for (according to the documentation). As you attempted `max_results` this tells me you are trying to migrate from the Core Reporting API V3, check out the [Migration Guide - Pagination documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/migration#pagination) to understand how to request the next 100,000 rows.

Stack Overflow extra tip. Include your error responses in your question, as it will likely improve your chances of someone being able to help.

Comment: The docs has been updated: `The Analytics Core Reporting API returns a maximum of 100,000 rows per request, no matter how many you ask for. ` under `pageSize ` section.

Answer (score 3):

You can use parameter `page_size: 10000`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I checked these docs but couldn't find any example for max-result

1. v3 doc  https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#maxResults
2. v4 batchGet doc https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet

It would be great if someone shares the JSON example of max-result. I'm getting an error message when I add **"start-index" : 1** and  **"max-results": 10**

```
"Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"start-index\" at 'report_requests[0]':
 Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"max-results\" at 
'report_requests[0]': Cannot find field.", {
```

Here is my JSON

```
{
    "reportRequests": [
        {
            "viewId": "112211828",
            "dateRanges": [
                {
                    "startDate": "30daysAgo",
                    "endDate": "yesterday"
                }
            ],
            "metrics": [
                {
                    "formattingType": "METRIC_TYPE_UNSPECIFIED",
                    "expression": "ga:searchUniques"
                }
            ],
            "dimensions": [
                {
                    "name": "ga:searchKeyword"
                }
            ],
            "orderBys": [
                {
                    "orderType": "VALUE",
                    "sortOrder": "DESCENDING",
                    "fieldName": "ga:searchUniques"
                }
            ],
            "samplingLevel": "DEFAULT",
            "start-index" : 1,
            "max-results": 10 // [Uptade] it should be "pageSize": 10
        }
    ]
}
```

**[UPDATE]**

"pageSize": 10 is works instead of "max-results"

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: He asks "how to pass: max-result parameter with this class" and I gave him a full of an object including the max-result parameter